# The mystery of user defined normalize function in sphere approximation program

Tags: c, opengl, graphics, glut

The below program converts the tetrahedron to semi - sphere using normalize function. But no OpenGL functions are called in normalize function. Only values of few variables are changed and not even passed to other function. How is this function working to normalize ?

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<GL/glut.h>
    #include<math.h>
    GLfloat v[4][3]={{0.0,0.0,1.0},{0.0,1.0,0.0},{-1.0,-0.5,0.0},{1.0,-0.5,0.0}};
    int n;
    GLfloat theta[3]={0,0,0};
    int axis=2;

    void normalize(GLfloat *pt)
    {
        double d=0;
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<3;i++)
            d+=pt[i]*pt[i];
        d=sqrt(d);
        if(d>0)
            for(i=0;i<3;i++)
                pt[i]/=d;
    }
    void triangle(GLfloat* a,GLfloat* b,GLfloat* c)
    {
    //  glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
         glVertex3fv(a);
         glVertex3fv(b);
         glVertex3fv(c);
        glEnd( );
    }

    void divide_triangle(GLfloat* a,GLfloat* b,GLfloat* c,int m)
    {
        GLfloat v1[3],v2[3],v3[3];
        int j;

        if(m>0)
        {
            for(j=0;j<3;j++)
            {
                v1[j]=(a[j]+b[j])/2;
                v2[j]=(a[j]+c[j])/2;
                v3[j]=(c[j]+b[j])/2;
            }

            normalize(v1);         // normalize function called from here
            normalize(v2);
            normalize(v3);

            divide_triangle(a,v1,v2,m-1);
            divide_triangle(c,v2,v3,m-1);
            divide_triangle(b,v3,v1,m-1);
            divide_triangle(v1,v2,v3,m-1);
        }
        else
            triangle(a,b,c);
    }

    void tetrahedron(int m)
    {
    //  glColor3f(0,1,0);                       // green
    //  divide_triangle(v[3],v[2],v[1],m);                      // bottom face of semi-sphere
        glColor3f(1,0,0);                       // red
        divide_triangle(v[0],v[1],v[2],m);
        glColor3f(0,0,1);                       // blue
        divide_triangle(v[0],v[3],v[1],m);
        glColor3f(0,0,0);                       // black
        divide_triangle(v[0],v[2],v[3],m);
    }
    void spin()
    {
        theta[axis]=theta[axis]+0.05;
        if(theta[axis]>0.06)
            theta[axis]=0;
        glutPostRedisplay();
    }
    void mouse(int btn,int state, int x,int y)
    {
        if(btn==GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON&&state==GLUT_DOWN)
            axis=0;
        if(btn==GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON&&state==GLUT_DOWN)
            axis=1;
        if(btn==GLUT_MIDDLE_BUTTON&&state==GLUT_DOWN)
            axis=2;
    }

    void display()
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glRotatef(theta[0],1,0,0);   // x-axis spin
        glRotatef(theta[1],0,1,0);   // y-axis spin
        glRotatef(theta[2],0,0,1);   // z-axis spin

        tetrahedron(n);
        glFlush( );
    }

    void myinit( )
    {
        glClearColor(1,1,1,1);
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity( );
        glOrtho(-2,2,-2,2,-2,2);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    }

    void main()
    {
        printf("No of divisions : ");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGB|GLUT_DEPTH);
        glutInitWindowSize(500,500);
        glutCreateWindow("3D SEMI SPHERE APPROXIMATION BY SIERPINSKI GASKET ");
        glutDisplayFunc(display);
        glutIdleFunc(spin);
        glutMouseFunc(mouse);
        myinit( );
        glutMainLoop( );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program has its own normalize function. Each triangular face is recursively divided into four equal sized smaller triangles, by finding the midpoint of each edge. These midpoints are in the wrong position to sit on the surface of a sphere, so the normalize function is used to equalize the radius of each interpolated point from the centre of the sphere with the radius of the existing points. The deeper the recursion, the closer to a sphere it gets.

I don't know why you find the `normalize` function a mystery. It is a perfectly normal (excuse the pun) way of scaling the three components so that their magnitude is 1 (unless all are 0).

The recursive function `divide_triangle` passes each sub-triangle to openGL in the last line `triangle(a,b,c);` which is when the recursion depth limit has been reached. Below that depth, the triangles are split. At that depth, they are passed to the graphics engine.

Comment: My question was not why normalize function was used. The question i asked was, how is the function actually working? Since there are no OpenGL functions in the above normalize function, how is it able to control the triangles?

Comment: OpenGL does not have a monopoly. The function works by calculating the magnitude, namely the square root of the sum of the squares of each of the three components of the vector, and then scales each of those components so as to make the magnitude 1. That's how normalization works.

Comment: @VarunSharma I added more explanation to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for explanation but it didn't answer my question. In the above normalize(return type void) function it is performing calculations but it is not passing those values to any functions. Then where is the calculated values(in array pt) being used ?

Comment: The vectors are passed as pointers, and it modifies them directly. If the recursion limit has not been reached, three new vertices are created by interpolation. Each vertex is an array or x-y-z coordinates. The `normalize` function adjusts these values so that the vector length is `1`. Then each of 4 new triangles are passed to the recursion. If the limit was reached, the triangle is handed to openGL function via `triangle`. If not, four more triangles are created. I don't know how much clearer I can put this.

Comment: @VarunSharmaI I am not going to accept your edit to my answer. Your question was about openGL, graphics, glut. Not about how you pass function arguments.